# How do you connect to specific schema in Postgres? (Python, Sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgis

How do you connect to specific Postgres schema using Sqlalchemy?

So I've created a new schema called "rezerwacja_domkow". I can see it in Pgadmin4. But the whole schema system confuses me (so far I've played only with sqlite which was much more straightforward). I have no clue how to connect to it and work only in this schema.

When I connect to the main db I see:

```
            List of schemas
       Name        |       Owner       
-------------------+-------------------
 public            | pg_database_owner
 rezerwacja_domkow | postgres
 tiger             | postgres
 tiger_data        | postgres
 topology          | postgres
(5 rows)
```

But when I try to list table names using Sqlalchemy inspector I don't see any tables from "rezerwacja_domkow" schema.
I'd like to "connect" to this specific schema and modify / add data only to this one.
Your help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take half an hour out to at least skim the [official manuals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/). Schemas are just like directories or any other namespace. Just like directories let you have two files with the same name "dir1/file1.txt" and "dir2/file2.txt" so schemas let you have two tables with the same name.

And, just like with directories you either need to give the full path to a file ("dir1/file1.txt") or specify some other way to find it. With unix/linux systems there is the concept of a "search path" which is held in a variable and for example saves you having type "/usr/bin/date". Instead you can just type "date", hit enter and your computer will check all the directories in the `$PATH` variable in order.

Exactly the same situation applies in PostgreSQL. You can either refer to a table by its full schema:

```
SELECT * FROM rezerwacja_domkow.table1
```

Or let your search-path handle it

```
SET search_path=rezerwacja_domkow,some_other_schema,public;
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Like most other PostgreSQL settings you can provide a default value for the `search_path` for a specific database or user (`ALTER DATABASE ...` or `ALTER USER ...`) or just set it on connection or in a session like I showed above.

Plenty of examples of doing this online.

Answer (score -2):

To connect to the specific schema you first need to create database URL. This can be done as:

```
database_url = "postgresql://username:password@host:port/database_name?currentSchema=rezerwacja_domkow"
```

The "currentSchema" property is referring to the schema selected.

Next, create engine:

```
engine = create_engine(database_url)
```

Now, to execute query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
result = engine.execute(query)
```

In the end close connection:

```
result.close()
engine.dispose()
```

*Replace table names & credentials accordingly.

Reference-1: https://analyzingalpha.com/connect-postgresql-sqlalchemy

Reference-2: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html